# Positive integers $m$ such that $2m^2-1=x^4+y^4$ for some $x,y\in\{0,1,\ldots\}$ with $|x-y|>1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I note that
$$2(n^2+n+1)^2 -1= n^4+(n+1)^4.$$
This leads me to pose the following question.

**Question 1.** Are there infinitely many positive integers $m$ such that $2m^2-1=x^4+y^4$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb N=\{0,1,\ldots\}$ with $|x-y|>1$?

I have found totally $53$ such positive integers $m$ below $10^8$, the list of them is available from http://oeis.org/A343913 .  Here I give a new larger example:
$$2\times188717259^2-1=15335^4+11234^4. $$
I guess that there are infinitely many such positive integers $m$.

I also observe that
$$2(n^2+3)^2-2^4= (n+1)^4+(n-1)^4\ \ \mbox{with}\ n+1-(n-1)=2.$$
I have the following question analogous to Question 1.

**Question 2.** Are there infinitely many positive integers $m$ such that $2m^2-2^4 =x^4+y^4$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb N$ with $|x-y|>2$?

I have found totally $62$ such positive integers $m$ not exceeding $10^8$, the list of them is available from http://oeis.org/A343917 . For example,
$$2\times97077407^2-2^4=11563^4+5583^4.$$
I also guess that Question 2 has a positve answer.

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: You can conjecture for $2m^2-a^4=x^4+y^4$ using a famous identity $a^4+b^4+(a+b)^4=2(a^2+ab+b^2)^2$